# Including two js files

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pull in two js files. When both are included, one will not work.

Here is my js:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/js/select2.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
     $(".select2").select2();
      });
</script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/js/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I include both then `select2.full.min.js` will not work and I need both to be working. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: does `$(".select2").select2();` need both js files? Also check your console for more information. You might need to change the order or arrangement or one or both files might have an error some where.

Comment: Check what are the functions/methods that share common name which prevents one from not functioning. Check the console to trace the console errors

Comment: Are you sure, the path for select2.full.min.js is correct and its being downloaded by the browser ?

Comment: your some functions are not working not your file try to find manually same names and use noconflict function

Comment: @informer yaa the path is correct and its being downloaded by the browser

Comment: check your console , check error log

Comment: @Akin `$(".select2").select2();` this need only `select2.full.min.js` file but both the js works on same view

Comment: This is error i got when i did console.`TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`